# To assign multiple values to a set payload transformer in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

In order to set multiple values to a set payload transformer in mule we use

```
<set-payload value="#[{1000,1,1,1}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

can we assign multiple flow variables to a set payload transformer

```
<set-payload value="#[{flowVars['principal'],flowVars['years'],flowVars['rate'],flowVars['appid']}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Or is there any other right way to do it
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will work just fine. Whether you can do something that looks prettier, would be up to your full flow configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use as following :-

```
<set-payload value="#[flowVars['principal']] #[flowVars['years']] ..." doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```